# How can I replace old extension ladder rung springs and bolts?

Tags: repair

I have an old extension ladder and I need to replace the rung lock springs and bolts. I can't even tell the make or model of the ladder. I've searched Werner, Bird, Louisville but can't find similar parts. My rung lock is 6 3/8" long, simple aluminum.

Where else can I look or what do I measure to try to replace with newer Werner locks?

Comment: Imagine over time the designs have changed and old stuff is not available anymore.  Would measure the width and length of the ladder uprights and remove and bring one of the rung locks to a store that sells ladders.  Might be able to match something there.

Comment: Having that hardware fail while on the ladder makes kludging it a dicey proposition. Get a new ladder.

Comment: Aluminum ladders fatigue and are to be discarded. That's why the SF FD has a guy whose full time job is to varnish the wooden ladders that they, and only they, still use. (it was on Dirty Jobs)

Answer (score 3):

Ladders have a long history of lawsuits in the US. That's largely why all new ladders have many stickers full of warnings on them.

As such, "creative" ladder repairs are throughly unsupported, as nobody wants to be sued when your creative solution fails.

Thus, if you have an unidentifiable old ladder in need of repair, it's in need of replacement, and likely safest from your point of view to render it "no longer a ladder" before disposing of it, so you are not responsible for the next person getting hurt or killed.

If aluminum, scrap it (or scrap the top section and keep the bottom with feet as a non-extension, if it's otherwise solid. Having seen someone hurt themselves by using the top section with no feet as a separate ladder, ***don't do that.***

Comment: As much as I hate nanny-state labeling of everything (Prop 65 warning: The State of California is known to cause cancer), I would tend to agree with this. Having had the feet of a ladder (set on gravel) slide out from under me, it's not a fun ride down. Hacking up a new set of locks seems sketchy. However, if the OP is willing to use his own creation, I see no problem with him doing so, but I probably wouldn't use it.

Comment: Thanks guys. It's an old Keller 24'. I just needed 1 spring. Ladder is still very stable and safe. Admin please remove this post. Thanks again